# Latin for Choose

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would you write the following:

“Choose gentleness/kindness” Or even just “choose”, or “make a choice”, said as a directive? Or to say “You have a choice” “One has a choice”?

My thought behind this is to remember that there is always a choice to be made; that we are active agents in this life. I’d prefer something brief and maybe more open-ended. I originally thought to use “optio”. Would that be appropriate?

I’m planning to engrave this on a necklace as a sort of life mantra/ reminder. I might engrave gentleness on the back, if you have a translation suggestion for that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Optio is a noun.

Comment: Elige, or eligite, if the directive is for many people. The verb is [eligo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Deligo) . Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A literal translation would be:

> Delige humanitatem.

(One might also say *elige*. Döderlein's Handbook of Latin Synonyms [opines](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=do136): “**Deligere** means to choose, in the sense of not remaining undecided in one’s choice; **eligere**, to choose, in the sense of not taking the first thing that comes.” Make of that what you will …)

I am also partial to saying:

> Adhibe humanitatem.

[*Adhibere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dadhibeo) is a rather multi-faceted word, but in this case means “use, exercise.” When talking about people, it can also mean “summon, employ.” In my opinion, it does carry the idea of picking something out, consciously choosing something, but, if the idea of choice is important to you, this one does not make it explicit.

About the noun, I went with *humanitas*. [Döderlein again](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=do238): “Humanitas is a virtue of universal extent, which, like the mental cultivation, proceeding from intelligence, ennobles the whole man in mind and heart, and gives to his nature mildness and philanthropy, as a principle.” Another possibility would be *benignitas*.

Comment: Okay, that’s helpful. Thank you! 
It seems like “deligere” might work the best overall. If I want to extend the thought, how would I say “we are our choices”?

Comment: @user8637 Shooting from the hip I'd say something like: *Exsistimus ex quae deligimus*. If you want to know more, I think it would be best to post that as a new question.