# How do I best say “choose love” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-explanation

I’ve found power in the phrase “choose love” for a while, and feel drawn to write it out in Latin. For me, this phrase is a constant reminder to choose love (and by extension, choose being true to myself (love) over fear). It helps ground me to the truth of who I am, and what my goals in this life are- ie. remaining true to my highest self and always choosing the path of love over that of fear.

Tangent aside, in my research I’ve come upon two main ways I feel I could best use the word “choose”, those being either “opto” and “eligere”- with opto meaning more of an “I wish for, I hope for” and eligere meaning more “I choose between, I choose this above”. At least, this has been my understanding! I’m obviously not studied in the foundations of this incredible language, so I’m really looking to the larger community for support in how to choose the best words to fit my intention and phrasing, and also the order in which to write them.
When I look into how Latin can be written, it’s generally (and again I could be misinterpreting this wrong) more like French, where the verb follows the noun. But when I use Google translate (I know, definitely
Not the most reliable source of information), I’m given the order in reverse.
I know love has so many different ways of being written too. I’m not intending romantic love, more so the idea of love being a way of life and a way of moving with your soul, and in alignment with your highest self.

I would really love some support and help in understanding the foundations of this incredible language, and how to best go about finding the truth (in Latin) to such a powerful coupling of words. Thank you so much!

Comment: [Related question.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14983/latin-for-choose)

Answer (score 5):

*Elige ergo vitam* is a quote from the Vulgate (Deut 30:19) and it means, "therefore choose life". If you change *vitam* to *amorem* you'd have "therefore choose love".

There are other words besides *amorem* which can be picked for "love". If you want to keep with a biblical theme, you can use *caritatem*, since *caritas* is what the Vulgate uses to translate "love" in 1 Cor 13:13 (These three remain, faith, hope, and love, and the greatest of these is love: *manent fides, spes, caritas, tria haec: major autem horum est caritas*.)

Another option is *dilectio* from Song of Songs 8:6, "Strong as death is love", *fortis ut mors est dilectio*.

So *elige amorem*, *elige caritatem*, and *elige dilectionem* are all good options.